# Is there a way to force Visual Studio to open files from explorer in the same window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am a designer that has to work on multiple files across multiple projects. I rarely have an entire solution open, and instead look for files I need to modify in Windows Explorer.

Is there a way to force any files opened from Windows Explorer via either double-click or right-click to open in a new tab in the existing window?  Like, when I have to make a quick edit to 5 files, and I select them all and right click > open - it currently opens each in its own window instead of 5 tabs in one window, which I would prefer.

I see that there's a [file explorer extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7193af78-b06e-48dd-8994-9deb2bfa1959) that allows me to browse the filesystem from inside VS, but I was hoping to just be able to do it from Explorer directly.

Comment: On the computer I am working now, this is already the case. Everything opens in the active vs process with tabs. Don't know why but it just is. What do you have as the open with value of the files you try to open?

Comment: I think that was it. The behavior was erratic, and after some more investigation, I saw that some extensions were set to open with Visual Studio Version Selector instead of just Visual Studio.  Switching that to Visual Studio fixed the problem. @MartijnB - if you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is default behavior if you open the files with Visual Studio instead of Visual Studio Version Selector. You can change the open with value by going to the properties of a file.

Comment: This doesn't work for me with VS2012, you're talking about `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` right? If that's what I choose to open files with by default, they still each open in new VS2012 windows.

Comment: Same here, but only for .css files in VS 2013. double click .cs files opens as new tab, but double click .css files opens new window. Drag and drop works fine, but I want to know why the different behavior, and what reg hack fixes it (i am not using version selector.. using same path, devenv.exe, for both exts). (consider it an academic exercise, if nothing else). Thoughts?

Comment: Doesn`t help with VS2019. Still the files are opened in a new VS instance after changing "open with" to "Selector"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this doesn't fit your needs, but if you multi-select the files in explorer, then drag-and-drop them into  Visual Studio, it will open each file in a new tab.

Comment: This is exactly what I do. Beats double-clicking or right-clicking any day. Never underestimate the power of drag-and-drop!